# Why the <DIV> CSS applied for Repeater Control get Distorted when placed in UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, css, html, repeater

i am new to AJAX i am trying to update a Repeater Control When user Click on Search Button which is out side the updatePanel using Trigger event of UpdatePanel the  CSS get Distorted when Repeater Control is Placed inside UpdatePanel Whhen the Update Panel is Removed Then the CSS is applied perfectly why does it happen?

Code:

```
 <div class="jqueryresultsBackground">
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Repeater ID="ResultsRepeater" runat="server">
                  <HeaderTemplate>
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                          <tr>
                              <td>
                                  &nbsp;
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                      </table>
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <table align="center" width="100%">
                                  <tr>
                                      <td align="left" class="searchResFieldName" width="40%">
                                          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/deleted.png" 
                                              Style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; margin-left: -5px;" 
                                              Visible='<%# DeletedImageVisibility(Eval("IsActive"))%>' />
                                          <br />
                                          <%# Eval("UnicodeFullName")%>
                                      </td>
                                      <td width="10%">
                                         Col1
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </table>
                          </td>
                          <td width="10%">
                              Col2
                          </td>
                          <td width="10%">
                             Col3
                          </td>
                          <td width="8%">
                              Col4
                          </td>
                          <td width="5%">
                              Col5
                          </td>
                          <td width="10%">
                              Col6
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td align="left" class="searchResFieldName" width="35%">
                              <%# Eval("EnglishFullName")%>
                          </td>
                          <tr>
                              <td align="left">
                                  <%# Eval("HouseNumber")%>
                                  <br />
                                  <%# Eval("UnicodeAddress")%>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <b><%# Eval("ConstituencyNumber")%></b>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <b><%# Eval("PartNumber")%></b>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <b><%# Eval("SerialInPart")%></b>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <b><%# Eval("Age")%></b>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <b><%# Eval("Sex")%></b>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <b><%# Eval("CardNo")%></b>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>
                                  <%# Eval("Address")%>
                              </td>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>
                                  </td>
                                  <td align="left" class="searchResPrabhag" colspan="7">
                                      &nbsp;
                                  </td>
                              </tr>
                          </tr>
                          </table>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <hr />
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </ItemTemplate>


<FooterTemplate>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              &nbsp;
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                  </FooterTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater>
</ContentTemplate>

              <Triggers>
                  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SearchButton" EventName="Click" />
              </Triggers>

          </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="CurrentPageHiddenField" runat="server" />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is broken... The HeaderTemplate is closing your table.

Comment: Ohh yes..! Thanks a lot timdougall for spotting the Error..! Thank u again..!